# Method to backup files (not AMIs or snapshots) on AWS instance remotely

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS but I wish to backup my AWS server data files remotely. Most tutorials I found online are about using AWS Backup with EBS snapshots and AMIs. But those create dependencies on AWS. I want to be able to see my actual files somewhere else.

Now, my files are archived into single/multiple tar.gz files.

What is the best way to move them out remotely? They are 150GB in size and FTP-ing to a PC in my office takes 5 days! I'm looking for faster alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 to back up your files. It's secure, cheap, and highly available.

These are the steps to do it securely and in an automated manner:

1. Create an IAM role to allow the EC2 instance to access the S3 bucket
2. Assign that role to the EC2 instance
3. Install AWS CLI on your EC2 instance, if it's not already installed
4. Write a script to (sync or) copy the files to your S3 bucket.
5. (Optionally to save even more on S3 costs) Set a lifecycle management on your S3 bucket to move old files, that are not accessed/needed regularly, to another storage class (S3 Glacier for example).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to back up files outside of AWS. Many enterprises keep all their information inside AWS with no backups outside AWS, but keeping a backup elsewhere reduces risk of data loss.

From an EC2 instance you can send your data anywhere you like. An FTP / sFtp server, BackBlaze B2, Dropbox, etc. Most servers will be on high bandwidth links, 150GB shouldn't take very long. Note that in us-east-1 data egress is $0.09/GB so 150GB costs $13.50 to push outside AWS, though currently the first 100GB of traffic is free.

You could consider doing some kind of incremental backups using a tool such as [Restic](https://restic.net/) - or anything else you know / like. Restic is block based and can push backups to a variety of [destinations](https://restic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/030_preparing_a_new_repo.html) - ftp, Google, Azure, S3, Alibaba, REST server, rclone, etc. Because it's block based your second backup will likely use significantly less data than the first, reducing the AWS data egress costs. I've used Restic for years on PC / Linux, backing up locally and to S3.